# Logging for AWS ECS FARGATE

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, fluent-bit

I'm trying to use AWS Firelens for our FARGATE container logs. I'm are doing so by using the side-car method. Everything is working as expected. However I have one concern, i.e. if the logs in the source container is rotational. In other words, should I be worried about the disk space in our containers to run out because of the logs?

The reason why we ask this is because after enabling Cloudwatch Agent in the source container, I see that there is no change in the `disk_used_percent` at all. This is why I couldn't come to a conclusion. Can someone assist me with some information on the aforementioned question.

Comment: You can use CloudWatch to get/store logs from AWS Fargate and won't worry about disk.